# How to create a GIF from multiple image bitmaps in android

Tags: android, image, bitmap, gif

The main theme of my app is, user has to select images from his device gallery, and those selected images are turned into a **GIF.** I'm converting those selected images into bitmap and I am using this [GIFEncoder.java](https://github.com/nbadal/android-gif-encoder) file to converted selected images into a GIF, and I have achieved it. when I check it in my folder, GIF was created but when I open the GIF is was not animating just a black screen was appeared.

Here is my **MainActivity** looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 102;

private FileOutputStream outStream;
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<>();
private Button generateImageGIF, selectImages;

String BASE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "ImagesToGif";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    File mydir = new File(BASE_PATH);
    if (!mydir.exists()) {
        mydir.mkdirs();
    }

    generateImageGIF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.generate_image_gif);
    selectImages = (Button) findViewById(R.id.select_images);

    selectImages.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
        }
    });

    generateImageGIF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "gif creation started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(BASE_PATH + File.separator + getString(R.string.app_name) + ".gif");
                outStream.write(generateGIF());
                outStream.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "gif creation ended", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(data.getData()));
        bitmaps.add(bitmap1);
    }
}

public byte[] generateGIF() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    AnimatedGifEncoder encoder = new AnimatedGifEncoder();
    encoder.start(bos);
    for (Bitmap bitmap : bitmaps) {
        encoder.addFrame(bitmap);
    }
    encoder.finish();
    return bos.toByteArray();
}
}
```

Comment: Try looking into Animation Drawable [animation drawable](https://www.google.com.gh/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjT-deGktHUAhVqB8AKHd4XCgIQFgglMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fguide%2Ftopics%2Fgraphics%2Fdrawable-animation.html&usg=AFQjCNGep9UM8BgUrrl-6pRyZ8dSFYm7Ew) and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @KBJ, but issue was the GIF which was created doesn't contain the selected images. Just a black screen was appeared.